# Hiding deleted records from templates

Tags: ember.js, websocket, ember-data

I am trying to figure out if there's a better way to hide deleted records from a template and remove them from computed properties. My ember app is listening to a web socket and if another user deletes a record, there's a handler that removes that record from the store:

```
_handleDelete({id, type: modelName}) {
  const record = get(this, 'store').peekRecord(modelName, id);

  if (record) {
    get(this, 'store').deleteRecord(record);
  }
}
```

What I'm currently doing is defining a computed property that filters out any records where `isDeleted` is true, and using that for other collections:

```
allItems: computed.filter('items.@each.isDeleted', function(item) {
  return !get(item, 'isDeleted');
}),
```

Then I'm using this computed property to build other computed properties:

```
materialCosts: computed.filterBy('allItems', 'proposalCostType', 'material'),
```

This works fine, but the issue I'm having is that I didn't start with this, so many of my templates are referencing the hasMany relationship directly (`items`), rather than the filtered collection (`allItems`). It's a huge app so I'd have to update a TON of templates to get this working, and I don't think that's time efficient.

I never want a deleted record to ever display in the template and don't want any computed properties to be able to reference them, so ideally I'd be able to do something where the `items` relationship automatically filters out deleted records and is updated when they are removed.

I'm on Ember Data 2.14 so maybe there's a newer version that can do this? **Update** - Also tried on 2.18 just to see if it was the version I was using.

**Edit**

I tried what @Gennady Dogaev suggested below with unloading the record rather than deleting it, but ember gives me errors with computed properties that are watching the collection. For example, this one:

```
approvableItems: computed('items.[]', function() {
  return get(this, 'items').filterBy('isApprovable');
}),
```

... gives me an error that `isApprovable` can't be called on an undefined object.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If other user deleted record, it would be more correct to [unload](https://emberjs.com/api/ember-data/3.3/classes/DS.Store/methods/unloadRecord?anchor=unloadRecord) record from store. After that templates will stop rendering it, as if it never was in the store.

I don't recommend using `deleteRecord` in this case, because it dirties data in ember store. You supposed to call `record.save()` after calling `deleteRecord` but it will make http request to API which I think you don't want in described case.

---

In some cases you may encounter cryptic js errors:

1. If you try to push into store a new record with the same id as deleted
2. If user tries to re-visit route which tries to load deleted/unloaded record. This can achieved by using back/forward buttons in browser

If you encounter some errors in these scenarios, try to use following method for unloading records:

```
/**
 * This function unloads record from store and clears some private internals to avoid errors when UI tries to read
 * unloaded record from store
 *
 * @see https://discuss.emberjs.com/t/reusing-ids-for-soft-deleted-records/13715/6
 * @param store
 * @param model
 * @param id
 */
export default function(store, model, id) {
  let record, recordId, modelName;
  if (typeof model === 'object' && typeof model.get === 'function') {
    record = model;
    recordId = model.get('id') || id;
    modelName = model.constructor.modelName;
  } else {
    recordId = id;
    modelName = model;
    record = store.peekRecord(modelName, recordId);
  }
  if (record && !record.isDeleted) {
    store.unloadRecord(record);
  }
  if (recordId) {
    delete store.get('_identityMap')._map[modelName]._idToModel[recordId];
  }
}
```

I don't know if it still needed in latest version but I needed this code not so far ago.

Comment: This seems promising, but is causing a lot of errors when I try it. I'm seeing exceptions when the model is unloaded in computed properties that are referencing the record. If the record is deleted, it appears that the computed property is trying to get properties on undefined objects.

Comment: I updated my question with more info about the error I'm getting using unloadRecord.

Comment: @PeterBrown what exactly `items` is and how do you set it? You may need to remove your record from `items`, if it's not a result of one of store's methods.

Comment: It's a relationship on the model... `items: hasMany('item')`. I should add that the computed property I posted above is on that same model.

Comment: @PeterBrown I think you facing [this issue](https://github.com/emberjs/data/issues/4986) (unfortunately, Ember Data has a lot of issues when it comes to relationships). In [this thread](https://github.com/emberjs/data/issues/5424) people suggest using `store.push` to update relationships, which indeed may help. Also, if you didn't try function that posted in the end of my answer - try it, just in case.

Comment: Yea that does seem to be related, thanks! I don't have it working yet, but I'm going to accept your answer because it seems like it *should* work :)

Answer (score 1):

You can create template helper, and wrap `{{#each items}}` like `{{#each (only-active items)}}`

Comment: function ([items]) { return items.filterBy('isDeleted', false); }

Comment: If you read the OP's question, he wants a solution that doesn't require him to have to update every template

Answer (score 1):

You can try to exclude the deleted records directly on your view combining the built-in helper `unless` and the `isDeleted` property:

Read more about `isDeleted` here: https://www.emberjs.com/api/ember-data/3.3/classes/DS.Model

app/routes/todos/index.js

```
import Ember from 'ember';

export default Ember.Route.extend(AuthenticatedRouteMixin, {
  model(params) {
    return Ember.RSVP.hash({
      todos: this.store.findAll('todos')
    });
  }
});
```

app/controllers/todos/index.js

```
export default Controller.extend({
  actions: {
    deleteMe(todo) {
      todo.deleteRecord();
      console.log('deleting todo ' + todo.id); // Just to see if the action works
    }
  }
});
```

app/templates/todos/index.hbs

```
{{#each model.todos as |todo|}}
  {{#unless todo.isDeleted}}
    <li>{{todo.title}} - <a {{action 'deleteMe' todo}}>delete me</a></li>
  {{/unless}}
{{/each}}
```

Screenshot

[image: unless with IsDeleted]

You can clone my example code from https://github.com/hernanvicente/todos-placeholder

Answer (score 1):

A simple solution is do something like this. On your `template.hbs` do an each loop which is

```
  {{#each model as |todo|}}
    <li>{{todo.title}} - <a {{action 'removeRecord' todo}}>delete me</a></li>
  {{/each}}
```

If you do not want your record to be shown right after you deleted a record you can simply do the below. Btw, below is referenced by the ember-cli 1.13

```
removeRecord(todo) {
  todo.destroyRecord().then(() => {
    this.send('reloadModel');
  });
}
```

reloadModel is to reload your record once a record is deleted. However, if your backend does really remove the record once you sent a request for removing such a record it will remove your data once the `removeRecord` is being request to your API. Hope this would could help you.